# How to restrict JtextField from putting extra spaces in database?

Tags: java, database, jtextfield

Whenever I add values in database through JtexField it saves extra spaces in the sql database is there any way to restrict wide spaces and save only the text added in TextField?

```
try {
  String query = "insert into items (item_name, category_id, item_price, item_description, stock) Values (?,?,?,?,?) ;";
  PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
  pst.setString(1, textField_1.getText());
  pst.setString(2, textField_2.getText());
  pst.setString(3, textField_3.getText());
  pst.setString(4, textField_4.getText());
  pst.setString(5, textField_5.getText());

  pst.execute();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
  pst.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

spaces like this 
[image]

Trim function 
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by extra spaces ? spaces at start , at the end or in the middle  ?

Comment: Adeel as you can see spaces at the end ....

Comment: have you tried trim function on textfield ?

Comment: yeah but it did'nt work.

Comment: trim and then print it on console to check whether it trims the string or not. I don't see any problem in your code.

Comment: Adeel kindly check the code with trim function but it still saving spaces.

Comment: What is the data type of the column you're inserting to?

Comment: Its varchar(50) in sql database, david

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminates leading and trailing spaces:

1. Using String's trim() method

   textField_1.getText().trim();
2. Using Regex

   textField_1.getText().replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");

Comment: Sir its giving error for  "^\s+|\s+$", "" as: Invalid sequence

Comment: textField_1.getText().replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", ""); //try this

Comment: Tried sir but still saving spaces :(